# Why war file is not built in eclipse in spring mvc framework?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to build a maven build and create .war file. it shows the error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project EmpReg: Compilation failure: Compilation
>   failure: [ERROR]
>   /E:/Java_Project/EmployeeOnlineRegistrationForm/src/main/java/EmployeeOnlineRegistrationForm/controller/EmployeeRegistrationController.java:[13,47]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class CrossOrigin [ERROR]
>   location: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation [ERROR]
>   /E:/Java_Project/EmployeeOnlineRegistrationForm/src/main/java/EmployeeOnlineRegistrationForm/controller/EmployeeRegistrationController.java:[22,2]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol: class CrossOrigin

here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>EmpReg</groupId>
 <artifactId>EmpReg</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0</version>
 <name>SpringExamples</name>
 <description></description>
 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.5</source>
     <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

 <properties>
  <spring.version> 4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>

 </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
 <display-name>SpringExamples</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is my dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="EmployeeOnlineRegistrationForm.controller" />

 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
  <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1048576"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Have you tried to update your project?

Comment: which type of update?

Comment: right click on project icon (project explorer/package explorer)->maven->update project. Try "force update...". your pom contains spring-webmvc, which should be correct.

Comment: I did it. But did not work

Comment: The other thing that occurs to me is the path. Check Build Path ->Config... Make sure that in libraries tab the "maven dependencies" exits and contains the dependency in question. It is giving you a compile error. Missing symbol (in library)

Comment: has it ever worked?

Comment: Maven dependencies are there. It does not work

Comment: which java version are you using in eclipse build path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.
 1) I have downloaded cors-filter-2.2.1.jar added it.
 2) I have added maven dependency in pom.xml :

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
   </dependency>
```

3) I have extended my controller and override a method:

```
public class EmployeeRegistrationController extends OncePerRequestFilter {
@Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
                //LOG.trace("Sending Header....");
                // CORS "pre-flight" request
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
                // response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1");
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }


}
```

4) I have added filter on web.xml:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
        <filter-class>EmployeeOnlineRegistrationForm.controller.EmployeeRegistrationController</filter-class> <!-- your package name and filter class -->
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```